# Firebase email verification flow

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am a newbie to firebase. I need a way to verify an email address during the signup process. The user should NOT be automatically logged in without verification. What code can I add to allow me to check if the email is verified or not. If yes, the user can login. If not, they need to very first. Please see code below

```
async registerUser(customer: Customer, password: string) {
    try {
        const newUserCredential = await this.firebaseAuth.createUser(
            customer.email,
            password
        );
        // store user details in firestore
        this.firebaseStore.storeUserDetails(newUserCredential, customer);
        // send email verification
            await newUserCredential.user.sendEmailVerification();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        throw new Error(error.message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to check the [`emailVerified`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#emailverified) property on the [User](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User) object.

```
const {emailVerified} = this.firebaseAuth.currentUser

if (emailVerified) {
  // Email is verified
} else {
  console.log("Email is not verified")
  // Alert user
}
```